# Multiplying and Combining Matrices

Tags: matrix, mips, mars-simulator

Hi i am trying to write a code in mips assembly. The purpose of the code is to multiply two matrices. the user will be asked to enter two matrix parameters, the program will combine them and then the user will be asked to enter values into the matrix. finally the program will print the matrix. eg: user enters 3 x 2, 2 x 7 the program combines them to get 3 x 7, the user enters 21 values and then the matrix is printed

.text
start:
                li              $v0  4

```
            la              $a0  msg1

            syscall

            li    $v0 8

            la    $a0 matrix1

            li    $a1 3

            syscall

            li              $v0  4

            la              $a0  msg2

            syscall

            li    $v0 8

            la    $a0 matrix2

            li    $a1 3

            syscall

            li              $s0 2

    lb      $t0, matrix1($s0)       
            lb      $t1, matrix2($0)
    beq             $t1 $t0  values        


            li              $v0  4

            la              $a0  msg5

            syscall
```

exit:           li              $v0 10

```
            syscall
```

values:         lb      $t0, matrix2($s0)
                sb              $t0  matrix1($s0)

```
            lb      $t1, matrix1($0)

            li              $v0  4

            la              $a0  msg3

            syscall 

            mult           $t0 $t1                                                                                                                                                                            
            mflo           $s0
```

loop:           beq            $s1 $s0  print_matrix

```
            li             $v0 5

            syscall

            sb             $v0  matrix_values($t2)

            addi           $s1 $s1 1

            addi           $t2 $t2 1

            j loop
```

print_matrix:   li             $v0 4

```
            la             $a0 msg4

            syscall

            li             $v0 4

            la             $a0 matrix1

            syscall
```

print:          beq            $s2 $s0 exit

```
            li            $v0 1

            lb            $a0 matrix_values($t3)

            syscall

            li             $v0 4

            la             $a0 spaces

            syscall

            addi           $s2 $s2 1

            addi           $t4 $t4 1

            bne            $t0 $t4 print

            li             $v0 4

            la             $a0 newline

            syscall

            li             $t4 0

            j print
```

.data

msg1:           .asciiz "please enter first matrix parameters"

msg2:           .asciiz "please enter second matrix parameters"

msg3:           .asciiz "please enter matrix values"

msg4:           .asciiz "the result is"

msg5:           .asciiz "error"

spaces:         .asciiz "   "

newline:        .asciiz "\n"

matrix1:        .space 3

matrix2:        .space 3

matrix_values:  .byte

.align          0

Comment: I don't really understand your implementation of matrices here. Also your three backticks for code are formatted incorrectly.